# Is there any intersection in the applications of multi-agent reinforcement learning and more traditional branches of machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

From my limited understanding, it seems like the structure of problems that multi agent reinforcement learning attempts to attack is quite different from the structure of problems in more traditional areas of machine learning. Is this a correct assessment?

If so, is multi agent reinforcement learning doomed to be relegated to the backwaters of machine learning, in terms of applications?